# "cannot convert from 'Restsharp.method' to string 'string?'" using RestSharp Any updates

Tags: restsharp

[image: cannot convert from 'Restsharp.method' to string 'string?']

Can't seem to find any indication why every example is like this but doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

The RestRequest class expects two arguments: string and method. I can see you are only passing the method.
Eg:

```
public RestRequest(string? resource, Method method = Method.Get)
```

Please pass the string also. The string can be the endpoint of the API you are testing.

Please find the below code, which I used for public API, it should be working.

```
public void GetBookingDetails1()
{

 
    var restClient = new RestClient("https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com");
    var request = new RestRequest("/booking/1", Method.Get);
    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
 
    var response = restClient.Execute(request);

 
}
```